# JAX jacobian with right-hand-side matrix multiplication

Tags: python, jax

I would like to compute the jaxobian of a function, but in my code I need to multipy the vectors from the right side, i.e., instead of having `y = W@x` i have `y= x@W`. This is not a problem but i used `jax.jacobian` I get a matrix with the swapped dimension (i.e., when W is (3,2) a get a jacobian of (2,3)). Is there a quick way to solve this?

Here's a minimum working example:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

X = jnp.arange(3*10, dtype=float).reshape(10, 3)
W = jnp.ones((3, 2))

def funz(x):
    return jnp.dot((0.5 * x ** 2), W)

funz_jac = jax.jacrev(funz)

x = X[0]  # Example input for computing Jacobian
jac = funz_jac(x)
print(jac.shape)  # Output: (2, 3)
```

but I would like it to be (3,2) just like W.

Answer (score 1):

Your function maps an input of shape `(3,)` to an output of shape `(2,)`, thus *by definition* its Jacobian has shape `(2, 3)`. If you want the transpose of this, you can manually transpose the result, i.e.

```py
jac = funz_jac(x).T
print(jac.shape)  # Output: (3, 2)
```